# 2 AsyncTask to load JSON

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

What's the better implementation to do in my scenario?

I have 2 php pages that give me JSON responses, and on my android application I get all these JSON response on my SplashScreen and then save all the data on my SQLite...

So i was thinking, which one is the better implementation?

- Make 2 HTTP requests to load all the data on ONE AsyncTask, and then on my PostExecute method, finish() the splash screen

or

- Make 2 AsyncTask classes, one for each http request? and then, how can i finish my splash screen class? i mean, on which PostExecute?

Comment: I honestly don't know which one is better but if you choose to use two AsyncTaks for one activity then you can define a boolean flag with default value false, and in both AsyncTasks' postExecute method check the boolean value. If it is false make it true and if it is true finish the activity. This way whichever AsyncTask will finish first will make the flag true and the second AsyncTask can finish the splash activity.

Comment: Oh thank you :P, that's a cool way

Comment: and also don't forget to define the boolean flag as volatile because both the AsyncTasks will be running on separate threads trying to access same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two requests -> two `AsyncTask`s. Obviously that's faster for every given scenario.

As for how to finish the Splash screen go with the comment of @Setu